# 6PE (RFC 4798) support on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, ipv6

I notice that in the newer kernels, support for RFC 4798 has been added through the means of IPV4 mapped addresses. I do have a route pointing to the mapped address being the nexthop and I'm unable to `ping` the routes.

#### route added

```
abcd:4003:0:1::/64  encap mpls  2/300016  via ::ffff:3.3.3.3 dev eth12 proto 22 metric 1024 pref medium
```

I get the below error thrown when tried to ping:

ping6 abcd:4003:0:1:abcd:1:0:5

> connect: Address family not supported by protocol

also made sure i have a v4 route to 3.3.3.3 which is reachable

> 3.3.3.3 encap mpls 300016 via 192.168.1.2 dev eth12 proto 22

Does the kernel automatically translate the mapped address or has this support not yet added?

under sysctl -a , i see ipv6 is enabled and even allowing for mapped address is enabled.

`net.ipv6.bindv6only=0 and net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0)`

Comment: Hmm. That's the error you normally see if someone had disabled IPv6 system-wide on the system, e.g. by setting the disable_ipv6 sysctl or blacklisting the ipv6 module. Check that someone hasn't done anything to disable IPv6 on the system, even partially, or for a single interface.

Comment: under sysctl -a , i see ipv6 is enabled and even allowing for mapped address is enabled. (net.ipv6.bindv6only=0 and net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0)